# LibXML - Looping through nodes until

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to parse the below XML using Perl's XML::LibXML library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TaggedPDF-doc>  
 <Part>
  <Sect>
    <H4>2.1 Study purpose </H4>
    <P>This is study purpose content</P>
    <P>content 1</P>
    <P>content 2</P>
    <P>content 3 </P>
    <P>content 4</P>
    <P>3. Some Header</P>
    <P>obj content 4</P>
    <P>obj content 2</P>
  </Sect>
 </Part>
</TaggedPDF-doc>
```

For the Header Study Purpose, I'm trying to display all the related siblings. So my expected output is:

```
<H4>2.1 Study purpose </H4>
<P>This is study purpose content</P>
<P>content 1</P>
<P>content 2</P>
<P>content 3 </P>
<P>content 4</P>
```

My Perl code is below. I can display the first node.

Given a value of the first node,Study purpose, is there a way I can loop and print all the nodes until I hit a node containing a "digit followed by a '.'"?

My perl implementation:

```
my $purpose_str = 'Purpose and rationale|Study purpose|Study rationale';
$parser = XML::LibXML->new;
#print "Parser for file $file is: $parser \n";     
$dom = $parser->parse_file($file);

$root = $dom->getDocumentElement;
$dom->setDocumentElement($root);

for my $purpose_search('/TaggedPDF-doc/Part/Sect/H4')
{
    $purpose_nodeset = $dom->find($purpose_search);
    foreach my $purp_node ($purpose_nodeset -> get_nodelist)
    {
        if ($purp_node =~ m/$purpose_str/i)
        {
            #Get the corresponding child nodes
            @childnodes = $purp_node->nonBlankChildNodes();

            $first_kid = shift @childnodes;
            $second_kid = $first_kid->nextNonBlankSibling();
            #$third_kid = $second_kid->nextNonBlankSibling();

            $first_kid -> string_value;
            $second_kid -> string_value;
            #$third_kid -> string_value;
        }

        print "Study Purpose is: $first_kid\n.$second_kid\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(@childnodes);` after you set it to see what you are really getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not look at child nodes if you want siblings. Use `textContent` if you want to match the node's text content.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $file        = 'input.xml';
my $purpose_str = 'Purpose and rationale|Study purpose|Study rationale';
my $dom         = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);

for my $purpose_search('/TaggedPDF-doc/Part/Sect/H4')
{
    my $purpose_nodeset = $dom->find($purpose_search);
    for my $purp_node ($purpose_nodeset -> get_nodelist)
    {
        if ($purp_node->textContent =~ m/$purpose_str/i)
        {
            my @siblings = $purp_node->find('following-sibling::*')
                           ->get_nodelist;

            for my $i (0 .. $#siblings)
            {
                if ($siblings[$i]->textContent =~ /^[0-9]+\./)
                {
                    splice @siblings, $i;
                    last;
                }
            }

            print $_->textContent, "\n" for @siblings;
        }

    }
}
```